# How can I update the device data of array of Objects farms array?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean

Actually I want to add new device in farm array after searching for a specific farm array (search it using by _id) .How can I achieve this in node js using mongoose?I am having trouble to insert the data?I am new to mongoose. Please help.

My code produces

```
//addDevice
//map to required farm in which i want to add device
router.put("addDevice/:id/",(req,res) =>{
  const deviceName=req.body.deviceName;
  const deviceType=req.body.deviceType;
  const description=req.body.description;
  const deviceLocation=req.body.deviceLocation;
  const Parameter=req.body.Parameter;
  const Topic=("v1/"+farmName+"/"+deviceName+"/"+deviceLocation+"/"+Parameter);

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
    {$push:{"farm.0.device":{farm,deviceName,deviceType,description,deviceLocation,Parameter,Topic}},$currentDate:{lastModified:true,"deviceModifyDate":{$type:"timestamp"}}},
    {safe:true,upsert:true,multi:false,new:true},
        function(err,User){
    if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
    return res.send(err);
  }
  return res.status(200).json(User);
  });
});
```

```
{
    "_id": "5d3ac84a86688123789e13b2",
    "name": "Puja",
    "email": "puja@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$r17zOU1gTJvwoB.nBdRvi.qvDmsJhIlHbp//s8l0KEKgCEvbKoZAu",
    "location": "Delhi",
    "createdDate": "2019-07-26T09:30:50.243Z",
    "farm": [
        {
            "location": [
                "11.33,22.99"
            ],
            "farmAddDate": "2019-07-30T08:03:34.247Z",
            "device": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d402def7cef9f20c8272fc4",
                    "deviceName": " DeviceX01",
                    "deviceType": " Test",
                    "description": " This is a test",
                    "deviceLocation": "11.22,33.12",
                    "Parameter": " temp",
                    "Topic": "v1/ DeviceX01/11.22,33.12/ temp"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d42b664243d02054417e2ab",
                    "deviceName": " Test 001",
                    "deviceType": " 1",
                    "description": " 2",
                    "deviceLocation": "3",
                    "Parameter": " temp",
                    "Topic": "v1/ Test 001/3/ temp"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d42b8208c13262db052454f",
                    "deviceName": " ",
                    "deviceType": " ",
                    "description": " ",
                    "deviceLocation": [],
                    "Parameter": " ",
                    "Topic": "v1/ // "
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d42b8258c13262db0524550",
                    "deviceName": " ",
                    "deviceType": " ",
                    "description": " ",
                    "deviceLocation": [],
                    "Parameter": " ",
                    "Topic": "v1/ // "
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d440bd687241b23341ce2ab",
                    "deviceName": "Xkito",
                    "deviceType": "Musiic",
                    "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm",
                    "deviceLocation": [
                        "11",
                        "85.33"
                    ],
                    "Parameter": "Hello",
                    "Topic": "v1//Xkito/11,85.33/Hello"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d440bf50a3bbb2c9417bb53",
                    "deviceName": "Xkito",
                    "deviceType": "Musiic",
                    "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm",
                    "deviceLocation": [
                        "11",
                        "85.33"
                    ],
                    "Parameter": "Hello",
                    "Topic": "v1//Xkito/11,85.33/Hello"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d441348f1877637cc712d04",
                    "deviceName": "Xkito",
                    "deviceType": "Musiic",
                    "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm",
                    "deviceLocation": [
                        "11",
                        "85.33"
                    ],
                    "Parameter": "Hello",
                    "Topic": "v1/Xkito/11,85.33/Hello"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d3ff9d68e34cb265c030819",
            "farmName": "Durgapur",
            "description": "Testing that info is  saved "
        },
        {
            "location": [],
            "farmAddDate": "2019-08-01T11:48:01.883Z",
            "device": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d441348f1877637cc712d04",
                    "deviceName": "Xkito",
                    "deviceType": "Musiic",
                    "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm",
                    "deviceLocation": [
                        "11",
                        "85.33"
                    ],
                    "Parameter": "Hello",
                    "Topic": "v1/Xkito/11,85.33/Hello"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d42d171e7ceef2a90245470",
            "farmName": "Xilo",
            "description": "This is test from Postman Api Request"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "farmModifyDate": "6720163877251710977",
    "lastModified": "2019-08-02T10:41:12.141Z",
    "deviceModifyDate": "6720517743902195713"
}
```

I expect the device to added into a particular farm on request.

Comment: `I expect the device to added into a particular farm on request.` To identify in which farms device need to push, you should have farm's _id too.

Comment: `req.body` has farm Id?

Comment: No,I am not passing farm id in req.body  @HardikShah